# Get frontend coverage in razor page Visual Studio 2022

Tags: visual-studio, testing, code-coverage, test-coverage

Do you know if it is a good practice to check the code coverage for the frontend in a Razor app? If yes, how do I get the report for the frontend coverage result? All report only check backend coverage...